# NETLOGO: turtles-own except for breed1

Tags: netlogo

I do have several breeds: breed1, breed2, breed3, breed4, breed5.
Now I would like to define several variables belonging to the turtles for all breeds except breed1.

So do I have to write separately

```
breed2-own [variable1 variable2 variable3]
breed3-own [variable1 variable2 variable3]
breed4-own [variable1 variable2 variable3]
breed5-own [variable1 variable2 variable3]
```

or is there a possibility to say something like

```
turtles-own (except for breed1) [variable1 variable2 variable3]
```

???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: no, there is not.

But the real question is: if you have four different breeds with the same variables, do they really need to be separate breeds? It depends on the details of your model, of course, but instead of separate breeds with the same variables, you could have one breed with a `kind` variable used to differentiate turtles within that breed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I had already started doubting if I need to create several breeds before. But now your answer has convinced me finally to reduce the number of breeds in the model.